# LinkedIn social share rwd

Tags: magento-1.9, social-buttons

We use the original RWD social share see picture

[image]

We have add the LinkedIn Icon and we have open sharing.phtml but we do not know what to insert in the a href=""

```
<a href="<?php ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Share on LinkedIn')) ?>" class="link-linkedin"><?php echo $this->__('Share on LinkedIn') ?></a>
```

Do we need JS?

Module is not a possibility for us.

Thanks!

Comment: I have read this https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin but not sure if the best is API and how to add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to achieve product sharing via LinkedIn, add the following to your `href` attribute:

`<?php echo 'https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=' . urlencode(trim($_product->getProductUrl())) . '&title=' . urlencode(trim($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'))); ?>`

I would recommend following [RWD](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html)'s template flow and use the predefined `$_productName` and `$_productUrl` variables respectively.
So you would use:

`<?php echo 'https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=' . $_productUrl . '&title=' . $_productName; ?>`

**Resources:**

- [Responsive Web Design Developer's Guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html)
- [Share on LinkedIn](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin)

Comment: Work great the RWD template flow. Thanks bluemwhitew

Comment: No worries! You could also consider including the `summary` parameter in, but LinkedIn usually scrapes meta/Open Graph data from the URL anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to done this, https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share when you open this link, choose three options

1) which url you want to share

2) Language

3) Count Mode

click getcode to generate code, you paste this code wherever you want in your template file.

choose appropriate template file using debug mode then paste it.

**note:** In your case replace the anchor tag above you mention to genrated code

**Reference:** http://gworks.mobi/blog/category/magento/

Comment: We want to be able to share our product, not a like button. We already have it for facebook and twitter. Customer can share the product to other poeple.

Comment: hard to find, I felt not enough details have this question add some more details like fb,twitter codes then only compared to linkedin.